# SMD IC Marked 18R ID Help

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, gps

I need help identifying a 6 pin IC marked 18R, thanks in advance!

Additional Info

- Dimensions:
  ~1.6mm x ~1.6mm
- Pitch: ~.3mm
- Connected to the VDD pin of the [ICM-20948](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DS-000189-ICM-20948-v1.3.pdf) 9-Axis MEMS Motion Tracker
- Other IC shown is an [TXS0108E](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0108e.pdf) 8-Bit Bi-Directional, Level-Shifting, Voltage Translator

[image: 18R and surround]

Comment: Please include pitch and dimensions